# linux process constantly drops connections

Tags: linux, tcp, boost-asio

I have written a server application that is currently running on a Ubuntu 12.04 x64 VM. The application connects to another server, sucks some data from this server, transforms it and then sends it back to client applications running elsewhere. All of this is over boost::asio on top of TCP. IO is fairly heavy.

Every day after a couple of hours or so of operation we see our server dropping the client connections. When the clients try to re-connect their connections are again dropped as soon as they are established. The error report by boost::asio is "Connection reset by peer". This goes on seemingly indefinitely. During this time I can ssh into the machine and the connection from our application to the server process is still healthy. Load is moderate. Restarting our application solves the problem.

Any ideas on how to further investigate this?

Comment: 1. Does this happen in your development environment? 2. Do you have a tcp dump? 3. What is the server process, and what are on its logs? 4. Are there any firewalls, stateful firewalls, or routers which maintain any state between the hosts? 4. Do you have a strace output from the client?

Comment: Another option: what does `netstat -an` tell you (when the app is misbehaving)?

Comment: MarkR: 1) no, it doesn't happen anywhere but with this particular installations. 2) I am running tcpdump now. 3) The server process should not be relevant I think, its connection is holding steady through it all 4) I don't know - this is on a client site. 5) no. I'll try to get one.

Comment: ChrisopheD: nothing unusual, the connections I see are what I would expect.

Comment: Could be that there is a firewall or NAT box between the client and server. syn-cookies?

Comment: provide output of netstat -s. or if you want to do it your self, then see values of various parameters under Tcp and TcpEXT.

Answer (score 1):

Error ""Connection reset by peer" when clinet app tries to connect means that port application tries to connect is probable not open or it open, but can not receive additional connetions (server has a max number of not accepted connection).

On network level you'll see `SYN` sent by client to server and server responds with `RST`.

Run `netstat -antp` on server and see if server port is in `LISTEN` state.

Comment: Thanks dimba. The connection reset by peer message is shown by my server not the client (the client is a windows box). New connections seem to be accepted by the server but they are immediately dropped with the reset message.